# Inline Bootstrap form layout with labels above inputs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to create a form with the following layout using Bootstrap 3:

[image]

I have a jsfiddle with an attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/quyB6/

And the markup I've tried:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="lineHeight">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
        <input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="paddingTop" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="paddingBottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to add `col-xs-4` to the class of each div. That will make sure the divs will be inline for the jsfiddle example. Additionally, you should close the form tag with `</form>`.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How does this work, by the way? The documentation says that adding the class col-xs- affects extra small devices (< 768px). See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries.

Comment: My best guess would be that the viewport (the HTML section) in the JSFiddle example falls into the <768px category. If you resize the window for the HTML output it would probably go inline.

Comment: so this is why these were all over the code I inherited...

Answer (score 13):

With Bootstrap 4.4:

Use the class "form-row" in the form element.

```
<form class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="lineHeight">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
        <input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="paddingTop" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="paddingBottom">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This should be voted higher.  "form-row" (which uses flex) gives more consistent results compared to the other answers.

Answer (score 12):

For bootstrap v4 you can use `d-flex flex-column`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="lineHeight">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do not that your form should *not* have the class form-inline if you want to use it with labels on top of input fields

Comment: Without `form-inline` class, my inputs jump around when I activate them

Answer (score 11):

Replace `<label>` tag with `<div>` and it will line up on top perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore since v4-alpha.6. :(

Answer (score 1):

Putting `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` between the `<label>` and the `<input>` worked for me. I tried a bunch of the above ideas with no luck. This is with Bootstrap 3.3.7.

So

```
<label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label> 
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<input type="number" value='' class="form-control" id="lineHeight">
```

I also included `"pull-right"` as a class (i.e. `class="control-label pull-right"` and `class="form-control pull-right"` to get the label and the input on the right-hand side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" value='' class="form-control  bg-secondary text-white" id="lineHeight">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" value='' class="form-control  bg-secondary text-white" id="paddingTop" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" value='' class="form-control  bg-secondary text-white" id="paddingBottom">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

check:https://jsfiddle.net/89h0vrLq/